# How do I tell when my 'API contract' has changed using static analysis? (legacy spring-mvc / jsp application)

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a legacy java application that uses spring-mvc with jsp.

In order to provide more robust testing guidance / change impact analysis, I'd like to know when any class is changed that is depended upon by a spring-mvc controller.

Almost all methods in all classes in the system have a call hierarchy that eventually ends with one or more controller endpoints, and it is these controller endpoints I want to identify when a change is made in order to provide better test guidance.

For example:

`MyRepository` class is depended upon by `MyService` class, which is depended on by `MyServiceFacade` class, which is depended on by `MyManager` class, which is depended upon by `MyController` class and then the endpoint method defined in `MyController` class.

I want to be able to run static analysis to show `MyEndpoint` method `@RequestMapping` annotation if I change `MyRepository` or any other class depended upon by a method annotated with `@RequestMapping` (or similar annotations).

I could probably build tooling myself to achieve this, but I'm curious to know whether anyone has any tips on how to achieve this already with say, an IDE, an existing static analysis tool, analysis tool of some type or anything similar.

Comment: I am having some (early initial but not guaranteed) success using jdeps tool (ships with java8 +) and some visualisation of the dot output that it generates. No solid solution yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a tool called JCCI that can help you, and I'm the author and start opening recently,
pypi: https://pypi.org/project/jcci/
github: https://github.com/baikaishuipp/jcci

there is a sample result:[jcci result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNeAy.png)